# Filtering: How to hide/show (toggle) certain table rows on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, toggle, show-hide

Assuming this table (actually it could have more columns and rows):

```
<table id="vehicles">
  <tr>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Color</th>
    <th>Wheels</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Car</td>
    <td>Red</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Motorcycle</td>
    <td>Green</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bike</td>
    <td>Blue</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Car</td>
    <td>Blue</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bike</td>
    <td>Green</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Motorcycle</td>
    <td>Red</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now my goal is to be able to click on the table data (cells), for example "Car", and then show only the two cars. Another click on "Car" should show the hole table again. Or one click on "Red", and then only the red vehicles (red car and red motorcycle) should be shown. How can this be achieved using jQuery?

Comment: It can be achieved with jQuery.

Comment: Explain a bit more. where you want to click and what you want to get.

Comment: Where is your Jquery, you have tried so far?

Comment: @ControlAltDel: That wasn't the question.

Comment: the explanation of behavior is very poor in the question and no attempt has been made to try anything. We aren't here to write your code for you

Comment: @MdSalahuddin: I want to click on a table cell and the table rows, where the column-corresponding table cell is not equal should be hidden (and shown again by clicking again).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function () {
    $( "td" ).on( "click", function() {
        var type = $(this).text();
        $('td:first-child').parent('tr:not(:contains('+type+'))').toggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="vehicles">
  <tr>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Color</th>
    <th>Wheels</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Car</td>
    <td>Red</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Motorcycle</td>
    <td>Green</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bike</td>
    <td>Blue</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Car</td>
    <td>Blue</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bike</td>
    <td>Green</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Motorcycle</td>
    <td>Red</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Stores the text from current td, hides tr nodes which do not contain the text.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really *really* simple test that might help you get started.

```
    $(function () {
        $("#vehicles tr td").click(function () {
            var desc = $(this).html();
            $("#vehicles tr").css("background-color", "white");
            $("#vehicles").find(":contains(" + desc + ")").closest("tr").css("background-color", "red");
        });
    });
```

This assigns a click event to every TD element, stores its value somewhere and then checks if said value exists in the table, highlighting the elements that are matched. Give it a spin, I think it'll set you off in the right direction.