# I want to toggle the table rows filter based on the text from buttons

Tags: jquery, filter, html-table, toggle, show-hide

```
<button id="btn">Car</button>
<button id="btn1">Bike</button>
<table id="vehicles">
  <tr>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Color</th>
    <th>Wheels</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Car</td>
    <td>Red</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Motorcycle</td>
    <td>Green</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bike</td>
    <td>Blue</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Car</td>
    <td>Blue</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bike</td>
    <td>Green</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Motorcycle</td>
    <td>Red</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#btn").click(function() {
       var type = $(this).text();
        $('td:first-child').parent('tr:not(:contains('+type+'))').toggle();
    });
    $("#btn1").click(function() {
       var type = $(this).text();
        $('td:first-child').parent('tr:not(:contains('+type+'))').toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

Adding to: [Filtering: How to hide/show (toggle) certain table rows on click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25730217/filtering-how-to-hide-show-toggle-certain-table-rows-on-click)
Based on the solution provided by Itotally, I am filtering table rows based on the button(s) text. Is this the most efficient solution?

Comment: What do you want ? You want filter row based on the text of your button. And that's what you have...

Comment: Yes, this works but does someone have a better/more efficient way to do this?

Comment: The problem is that if you click "Car" and then "Bike" the filter gets messed up.

Comment: The drop-down only works the first time. If I first select Car, it filters Car, but if I then select Bike, it filters Motorcycle.

Comment: My bad. I've edit and correct my answer. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some other solutions

You can add a select with your choice and show only the selected item

Add the class type on td where you search.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qgqa68rw/)

```js
$("#choice").change(function(){
    var choice = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
    $("table tr").each(function (index) {
                if (index !== 0) {
                    $row = $(this);
                    var id = $row.find("td.type").text().toUpperCase();
                    if (id.indexOf(choice) == -1) {
                        $row.hide();
                    }
                    else {
                        $row.show();
                    }
                }
            });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="choice">
<option value>All</option>
<option value="Bike">Bike</option>
<option value="Car">Car</option>
</select>

<table id="vehicles">
  <tr>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Color</th>
    <th>Wheels</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="type">Car</td>
    <td>Red</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="type">Motorcycle</td>
    <td>Green</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="type">Bike</td>
    <td>Blue</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="type">Car</td>
    <td>Blue</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="type">Bike</td>
    <td>Green</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="type">Motorcycle</td>
    <td>Red</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This can minimize your number of button if there is a lot of choice

You can easily add a search in your table too

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="search" id="search">
```

**Jquery**

```
$("#search").keyup(function(){
    var search = $(this).val();
    $('td:first-child').parent('tr:not(:contains('+search+'))').toggle();
});
```