# Hide and Show a row of table based on the value of a dropdown - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

1. Now the Table is dynamic so  many rows can come but drop down is static
2. drop down 2nd and 3rd value Apple and Orange can only come in the tables 2nd column And dropdown 4th and 5 th value "Fresh" and "Rotten" can only come in the 4th column
3. all the code should be in the function viewChange ()

Now when `Apple` is selected all the rows with 2nd column value with apple will show and so on.

selection - All will show the whole table again

How do I write the function?

```js
    function ViewChange()
{

var selectedViewName = $('#dropDown :selected').val();
    switch (selectedViewName)
    {

       

        case("1"):
            selectedViewName="ALL";
            break;
        case("2"):
            selectedViewName = "Apple";
            break;
        case("3"):
            selectedViewName = "Orange";
            break;
        case("4"):
            selectedViewName = "Fresh";
            break
        case("5"):
            selectedViewName = "Rotten";
            break

}
```

```html
<select id="dropDown" onchange="ViewChange()"><option value="1">All</option>
  <option value="2">Apple</option>
  <option value="3">Orange</option>
  <option value="4">Fresh</option>
  <option value="5">Rotten</option>
</select>

<table id="tableID">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Fruit type</th>
      <th>place</th>
      <th>state</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>salim groceries</td>
      <td>apple</td>
      <td>nagpur</td>
      <td>fresh</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>monalisa groceries</td>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td>Belapur</td>
      <td>Rotten</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>taj groceries</td>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>Nasik</td>
      <td>Fresh</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>suraj groceries</td>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>Goa</td>
      <td>Rotten</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Please check out this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/shaswatatripathy/pvxmrL2n/8/

Comment: Do you have a question about this code? All I can see is your list of requirements

Comment: added the question

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35632168/i-want-to-toggle-the-table-rows-filter-based-on-the-text-from-buttons/35639792#35639792

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function ViewChange($this) {
    var $selectText = $('option:selected', $this).text().toLowerCase();
    var $val = $($this).val();

    if ($selectText != 'all') {
        $('tr').each(function () {
            if ($(this).find('td').length) {
                var txt = '';
                if ($val < 4)
                    txt = $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text().toLowerCase();
                else
                    txt = $(this).find('td:eq(3)').text().toLowerCase();

                if (txt === $selectText) {
                    $(this).show();
                }
                else {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            }
        })
    }
    else {
        $('tr').show();
    }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropDown" onchange="ViewChange(this)"><option value="1">All</option>
<option value="2">Apple</option>
<option value="3">Orange</option>
<option value="4">Fresh</option>
<option value="5">Rotten</option>
</select>

<table  id="tableID">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Fruit type</th>
            <th>place</th>
            <th>state</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <tr >                
                <td>salim groceries</td>
                <td>apple</td>
                <td>nagpur</td>
                <td>Fresh</td>
            </tr>
            <tr >
               <td>monalisa groceries</td>
                <td>Apple</td>
                <td>Belapur</td>
                <td>Rotten</td>
            </tr>
             <tr >
               <td>taj groceries</td>
                <td>Orange</td>
                <td>Nasik</td>
                <td>Fresh</td>
            </tr>
            <tr >
               <td>suraj groceries</td>
                <td>Orange</td>
                <td>Goa</td>
                <td>Rotten</td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: We don't have any data regarding those in `table`

Comment: see the 4th column in table

Comment: Check updated answer [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/an93ch1n/#&togetherjs=cudR1CCgCN)

Answer (score 1):

As you asked, I am adding one more solution where there is no changes in your HTML.

**Solution 1 : Without changes in HTML**

```js
document.getElementById("dropDown").addEventListener("change", viewChange)

function viewChange()
{  
  var value = $('#dropDown :selected').text();
  if(value=="All"){
   $("#tableID tbody tr").removeClass("hiddenItem");
  } else {
   $("#tableID tbody tr").addClass("hiddenItem");
    
   $("#tableID tbody tr td").each(function (key, tdElem) {
      
      if(tdElem.innerHTML.toLocaleUpperCase() == value.toLocaleUpperCase()){ 
                     $(tdElem.parentElement).removeClass("hiddenItem");
       }
         });
  }
}
```

```css
.hiddenItem {
  display : none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropDown"><option value="1">All</option>
<option value="2">Apple</option>
<option value="3">Orange</option>
<option value="4">Fresh</option>
<option value="5">Rotten</option>
</select>

<table  id="tableID">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Fruit type</th>
            <th>place</th>
            <th>state</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <tr >                
                <td>salim groceries</td>
                <td>apple</td>
                <td>nagpur</td>
                <td>Fresh</td>
            </tr>
            <tr >
               <td>monalisa groceries</td>
                <td>Apple</td>
                <td>Belapur</td>
                <td>Rotten</td>
            </tr>
             <tr >
               <td>taj groceries</td>
                <td>Orange</td>
                <td>Nasik</td>
                <td>Fresh</td>
            </tr>
            <tr >
               <td>suraj groceries</td>
                <td>Orange</td>
                <td>Goa</td>
                <td>Rotten</td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

**Solution 2 : With changes in HTML**

Try this, It works

```js
document.getElementById("dropDown").addEventListener("change", viewChange)

function viewChange()
{  
  var value = this.value;
  if(value=="All"){
   $("#tableID tbody tr").removeClass("hiddenItem");
  } else {
   $("#tableID tbody tr").addClass("hiddenItem");
   $("#tableID tbody ." + value).removeClass("hiddenItem");
  }
}
```

```css
.hiddenItem {
  display : none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropDown" ><option value="All">All</option>
<option value="Apple">Apple</option>
<option value="Orange">Orange</option>
<option value="Fresh">Fresh</option>
<option value="Rotten">Rotten</option>
</select>

<table  id="tableID">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Fruit type</th>
            <th>place</th>
            <th>state</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <tr class="Apple Nagpur Fresh">                
                <td>salim groceries</td>
                <td>Apple</td>
                <td>Nagpur</td>
                <td>Fresh</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="Apple Belapur Rotten" >
               <td>monalisa groceries</td>
                <td>Apple</td>
                <td>Belapur</td>
                <td>Rotten</td>
            </tr>
             <tr class="Orange Nasik Fresh" >
               <td>taj groceries</td>
                <td>Orange</td>
                <td>Nasik</td>
                <td>Fresh</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="Orange Goa Rotten" >
               <td>suraj groceries</td>
                <td>Orange</td>
                <td>Goa</td>
                <td>Rotten</td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: on the load , it does not display any row , it should have all as default and show the whole table , click on run code snippet and see

Comment: If it is a dynamic table, you will be able to add classes, all you need to do is to edit your html template

Comment: Edited the snippet to make all rows visible at load time

Comment: Added one more solution to cover your concern. Solution 1 is without any modification to your html, solution 2 is with changes to your html. I prefer to use solution 2, because that is more neat and clean way.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```js
$.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
  return function( elem ) {
    return $(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
  };
});
function ViewChange($this) {
  var pid = $('option:selected', $this).text();
  $('#tableID tr').hide();
  $('#tableID tr > td:contains(' + pid + ')').each(function () {
    $(this).parent().toggle(); 
  });
  if(pid == "All") { 
    $('#tableID tr').show();
  } else {    
    $('#tableID tr:first').show(); 
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropDown" onchange="ViewChange(this)"><option value="1">All</option>
<option value="2">Apple</option>
<option value="3">Orange</option>
<option value="4">Fresh</option>
<option value="5">Rotten</option>
</select>

<table  id="tableID">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Fruit type</th>
    <th>place</th>
    <th>state</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr >                
    <td>salim groceries</td>
    <td>apple</td>
    <td>nagpur</td>
    <td>Fresh</td>
  </tr>
  <tr >
    <td>monalisa groceries</td>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>Belapur</td>
    <td>Rotten</td>
  </tr>
  <tr >
    <td>taj groceries</td>
    <td>Orange</td>
    <td>Nasik</td>
    <td>Fresh</td>
  </tr>
  <tr >
    <td>suraj groceries</td>
    <td>Orange</td>
    <td>Goa</td>
    <td>Rotten</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pvxmrL2n/10/

Answer (score 0):

You can go trough this file and check the functionality which can auto check every text

```
https://jsfiddle.net/pvxmrL2n/23/


https://jsfiddle.net/pvxmrL2n/23/

https://jsfiddle.net/pvxmrL2n/23/
```

```js
function ViewChange(miljo)
{
var res = miljo.toLowerCase();
var rows = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].rows;
var count=0;
for(count = 0; count < rows.length; count++)
   {
   var j=0;



   if(rows[count].className=='allrecords'){

   if(res=='all')
   {
    rows[count].style.display = '';
   }else{
    rows[count].style.display = 'none';
   for ( j = 0;   j < rows[count].cells.length; j++) {

      var contentval=rows[count].cells[j].innerText;
         contentvallwr=contentval.toLowerCase();
         if(res==contentvallwr)
         {
rows[count].style.display = '';
          break;
         }
    }  
    }
   }
  }

}
```

```html
<select id="dropDown" onchange="ViewChange(this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML)">
<option value="1">All</option>
<option value="2">Apple</option>
<option value="3">Orange</option>
<option value="4">Fresh</option>
<option value="5">Rotten</option>
</select>
<table  id="tableID">
    <thead>
        <tr class="head">
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Fruit type</th>
            <th>place</th>
            <th>state</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <tr class="allrecords"  >                
                <td>salim groceries</td>
                <td>apple</td>
                <td>nagpur</td>
                <td>Fresh</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="allrecords">
               <td>monalisa groceries</td>
                <td>Apple</td>
                <td>Belapur</td>
                <td>Rotten</td>
            </tr>
             <tr class="allrecords">
               <td>taj groceries</td>
                <td>Orange</td>
                <td>Nasik</td>
                <td>Fresh</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="allrecords">
               <td >suraj groceries</td>
                <td>Orange</td>
                <td>Goa</td>
                <td>Rotten</td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```