# Hide/show (toggle) table rows on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, html-table, toggle

```
$(function () {
    $( "td" ).on( "click", function() {
        var type = $(this).text();
        $('td:first-child').parent('tr:not(:contains('+type+'))').toggle();
    });
});


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="vehicles">
  <tr>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Color</th>
    <th>Wheels</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Car</td>
    <td>Red</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Motorcycle</td>
    <td>Green</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bike</td>
    <td>Blue</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Car</td>
    <td>Blue</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bike</td>
    <td>Green</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Motorcycle</td>
    <td>Red</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Following up to: [How to hide/show (toggle) certain table rows on click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25730217/filtering-how-to-hide-show-toggle-certain-table-rows-on-click) This works as long as the table elements are toggled on/off, but if you select an item in one row and then select an item in another row, the filtering gets messed up.

Comment: So, what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a better way to do this, but if you just kept track of what the last clicked type and the if the table already is filtered, you can be more clear on when you need to reset the table or apply the filter.

https://jsfiddle.net/wilchow/stnnuw0a/1/

```
$(function () {
        var last_type = null;
    var filtered = false;
    $( "td" ).on( "click", function() {
            console.log("last_type: "+last_type);
        var type = $(this).text();
        console.log("type: "+type);
        if(filtered && last_type == type) {
            // type is already filtered. Show all.
            $("tr, td").show();
          last_type = null; // reset
          filtered = false; // reset
        } else {
            $("tr, td").show(); // show all before filtering
            $('td:first-child').parent('tr:not(:contains('+type+'))').hide();
          filtered = true; // set filter flag to true
        }
        last_type = type; // set last type clicked
    });
});
```